# iOS 5 Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, ios5, uistoryboard

I am writing an app and for the first time I want to integrate some Facebook SDK functionality. I want to have the user login to their Facebook account, then be able to choose one of their friends to "compete" against in the app.

I am following the instructions on the Facebook developers site for iOS but what I can't seem to figure out is how to present a "login with Facebook" view when the app is launched and then never again while the Facebook SSO is authorized or unless the user logs out of the app.

The example I'll use for this is like the DrawSomething app's workflow for authentication.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this? Tutorials or examples would be awesome! I am using iOS 5 with storyboards for the app if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

First authenticate :
[Facebook API/SDK integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/)